# Problema al guardar un fichero en un array

Tags: java, array

tengo una duda. Estoy intentando guardar un fichero en un array [], pero no me sale nada, directamente me sale null.

```
public static Objeto[] leerFichero() throws Exception {
        String linea;
        Objeto[] datos = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduzca opcion: 1 para fichero 1, 2 para fichero 2");
            int opciond = input.nextInt();//mirar a ver si funciona esto, por que no va
            String cadena = "";

            if (opciond == 1)
                cadena = "ruta";
            else if (opciond == 2)
                cadena = "ruta2";
            FileReader f = new FileReader(cadena);
            BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(f);

            while ((linea = leer.readLine())!=null) {
                 String[] line = linea.split("\t");
                 int ide = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                 int dia = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                 int mes = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
                 new Objeto(ide, dia, mes);
            }
            leer.close()

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error, debe insertar una opcion valida");

        }
        System.out.println(datos);
        return datos;
    }
```

> El resultado que me da es null. No sé como guardar el fichero en el array.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en ningún momento creas un objeto de tipo `Objeto[]`. Por ende, la variable `datos` quedará apuntando a `null` **siempre**.

Ahora, el problema de usar un array es que no sabes la cantidad de elementos que tiene el archivo, por lo tanto, una opción es usar la clase [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), ya que no tenemos que preocuparnos en especificar el tamaño del array.

**Solución:**

```java
public static List<Objeto> leerFichero() throws Exception {
        String linea;
        List<Objeto> datos = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduzca opcion: 1 para fichero 1, 2 para fichero 2");
            int opciond = input.nextInt();//mirar a ver si funciona esto, por que no va
            String cadena = "";

            if (opciond == 1)
                cadena = "ruta";
            else if (opciond == 2)
                cadena = "ruta2";
            FileReader f = new FileReader(cadena);
            BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(f);

            while ((linea = leer.readLine())!=null) {
                 String[] line = linea.split("\t");
                 int ide = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                 int dia = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                 int mes = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
                 datos.add(new Objeto(ide, dia, mes));
            }
            leer.close()

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error, debe insertar una opcion valida");

        }
        System.out.println(datos);
        return datos;
    }
```